# Manage of Activities (back)order

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

This is theoretic question but I need some advice. I have complicated logic of switching between my activities. One part is easy: ActualActivity --> start next. The problem is with  previousActivity <-- ActualActivity (by back button e.g.). What can I do if I can walk in cycle? **And when I achieve last Activity of logic process and I need to finish last 4 Activities which precede this proces!?** Naturally I don't want to call back on each of them.

This is one of reasons why I decide to call finish() on each activity by default. I overrode StartActivity and put there finish(). I also fixed set backIntent for each Activity. But sometimes it is not enough. **Is it possible to send Intent some way to another Activity?** For better understanding of my idea: *intent.putExtra(BackIntent)*

It is clear to me that it is not common and good solution. **How can I manage "onPaused" activities which are not needed? How can I find out if activity is paused and call resume on it?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to read documentation about **Intent Flags**:

- http://blog.akquinet.de/2010/04/15/android-activites-and-tasks-series-intent-flags/
- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

This is how you can control all that is related to activity stack and storyboard.

Comment: If you describe more the workflow you want (precisely) we could have you find the right flags.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem can be resolve with "startactivityforresult"

```
//Activity A
private void someMethod()
{
   this.startActivityForResult(intentForActivityB, 123456);
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int request, int result, Intent intent)
{
   if(request == 123456 && result == Activity.RESULT_OK)
       this.finish();

   super.onActivityResult(request, result, intent);
}


//Activity B
private void someMethod()
{
   this.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
   this.finish();

}
```

this will close activity A when the Activity B is OK (setResult), an only in this case